# node.js about exports

Tags: node.js, export

I've been trying to get my head around node.js so I've been taking apart the chat demo they made here http://chat.nodejs.org/

I'm getting round to understanding it apart from this line `var fu = exports;`. Could anyone help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`exports` is a special local variable in node.

It's basically a variable you can add properties to that will be exported when another module require's your module.

So `var fu = exports;` is saying alias exports to `fu`. This means you can add properties to `fu` and they will exported by default.

So there are two similar patterns

```
var MyModule = exports;

MyModule.x = ...;
```

or

```
var MyModule = { x: ... };

module.exports = MyModule
```

The important thing of both cases is that `exports.x` is set so that when you require MyModule you can use `require("MyModule").x`

Comment: Thanks for that, in my code I'm not adding a module but the code uses 'fu' so instead of 'fu = exports' could I use 'fu = {}"?

Comment: @jonathandey yes that's valid as well, note that `exports` defaults as an empty object